# Parse PDB using DSR-PDB Library

Tags: bioinformatics, structural-biology, pdb

I'm trying to parse ATOM section of a PDB file. I'm using the `dsr-pdb` library for this purpose.

I've encountered a problem. This library interprets CD1 atom of ILE residue in the PDB file as AL_CD instead of AL_CD1*. Does it have a particular reason?

It's maybe helpful that within the source code, in `Residue_data.cc`, there is a mapping between atom lebels:

```
Atom_fallback_data atom_fallback_data_[]=
      {{Residue::AL_CD1, Residue::AL_CD},
       {Residue::AL_1HA, Residue::AL_HA},
       {Residue::AL_1HB, Residue::AL_HB},
       {Residue::AL_1HD, Residue::AL_HD},
       {Residue::AL_1HE, Residue::AL_HE},
       {Residue::AL_1HZ, Residue::AL_HZ},
       //{Residue::AL_1HH, Residue::AL_HH},
       {Residue::AL_1HD1, Residue::AL_1HD},
       {Residue::AL_2HD1, Residue::AL_2HD},
       {Residue::AL_3HD1, Residue::AL_3HD},
       {Residue::AL_INVALID, Residue::AL_INVALID}};
```

It means that AL_CD1 is deliberately converted to AL_CD or for example AL_1HA to AL_HA.

Thanks.

---

- In general, in dsr-pdb library, AL_X is the atom label of atom X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isoleucine only has one delta carbon, which we can just call `CD`. But it seems like some PDB files still name it `CD1`, and hence programs map `CD1` to `CD` in this case. (E.g. see [this tutorial](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Training/Tutorials/namd/namd-tutorial-unix-html/node6.html) where this practice is shown.)